# Which is better playing from extenral cdn or own file system on jw player

Tags: html, video, nodes, jwplayer

```
//Typical jw player setup  
jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
    "file": "/myVideo.mp4",
    "image": "/myImage.png",
    "height": 360,
    "width": 640
});
```

Will using video on my file system, take more bandwidth. Which is better using external source or my server space. And is it safe to use the jw player license key in js code.

Comment: serving from an external source/host will take up less bandwidth to your server, but will potentially incur costs where you host the video. including jw license key (if it's tied to the domain) is as designed. suggest you edit the question to make it clear what you're trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe to use the JW Player License key in Javascript code. The JW Player installation guide does not mention that having the license key publicly available can be a security problem.

If your hosting plan allows for enough bandwidth to serve the video, then you can host it on your own server